# Generate .txt file from string and force download in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, file, download

I use jQuery and JavaScript to build a web application.

I want to somehow create a .txt file from a JS string and force the client's browser to download this file.

Preferably the file should not be saved on the server.

Comment: What language are you using?  C#, VB, PHP??

Comment: try this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server